# Add Countif to Array Formula (Subtotal) in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, countif, array-formulas, subtotal

I am new to array formulae and have noticed that while `SUBTOTAL` includes many functions, it does not feature `COUNTIF` (only `COUNT` and `COUNTA`).

I'm trying to figure out how I can integrate a `COUNTIF`-like feature to my array formula.

I have a matrix, a small subset of which looks like:

```
A   B   C   D   E
48  53  46  64  66
48      66  89
40  38  42  49  44

37  33  35  39  41
```

Thanks to the help of [@Tom Shape](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3894917/tom-sharpe) [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495142/average-the-sum-of-rows-without-a-creating-new-column-in-excel), I (he) was able to average the sum of each row in the matrix provided it had complete data (so rows 2 and 4 in the example above would not be included).

Now I would like to count the number of rows **with complete data (so rows 2 and 4 would be ignored)** which include at least one value above a given threshold (say 45).

In the current example, the result would be 2, since row 1 has 5/5 values > 45, and row 3 has 1 value > 45. Row 5 has values < 45 and rows 2 and 3 have partially or fully missing data, respectively.

I have recently discovered the `SUMPRODUCT` function and think that perhaps `SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:E1 >= 45` could be useful but I'm not sure how to integrate it within [Tom Sharpe's elegant code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495142/average-the-sum-of-rows-without-a-creating-new-column-in-excel), e.g.,

```
=AVERAGE(IF(SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(A1,ROW(A1:A5)-ROW(A1),0,1,COLUMNS(A1:E1)))=COLUMNS(A1:E1),SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(A1,ROW(A1:A5)-ROW(A1),0,1,COLUMNS(A1:E1))),""))
```

**Remember, I am no longer looking for the average: I want to filter rows for whether they have full data, and if they do, I want to count rows with at least 1 entry > 45.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. Enter as array formula.

```
=COUNT(IF(SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET(A1,ROW(A1:A5)-ROW(A1),0,1,COLUMNS(A1:E1)))>45,IF(SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET(A1,ROW(A1:A5)-ROW(A1),0,1,COLUMNS(A1:E1)))=COLUMNS(A1:E1),SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(A1,ROW(A1:A5)-ROW(A1),0,1,COLUMNS(A1:E1))))))
```

Data

[image: Formula]